# superclass mismatch for class usercontroller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created API in rails 5.

I am getting error **superclass mismatch for class UsersController**.

My controller:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      def index
        users = User.Order('created_at DESC')
        render json: {status:"SUCCESS", message:"Load Users", data:users}, status: :ok 
      end

      def create
        user = User.new(user_params) 
      end

      def user_params
        params.permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :age, :id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

I got below error in console:

[image]

Actually, I have just started in ruby on rails. I tried to figure out problem but couldn't find it.

Comment: Do you need the module API and V1?, and declare the class like this: ‘class Api::V1::Userscontroller < ApplicationController’

Comment: @KevinEtore - you're wrong. There is a huge difference between declaring it the "longhand" way as the OP has done and using `class Api::V1::Userscontroller` as the later does not "open" the module so any references have to be fully qualified (Api::V1::Foo).

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference ApplicationController from the `Main` module (the "global" namespace in Ruby):

```
module Api
  module V1
    class UsersController < ::ApplicationController
```

`::` tells Ruby to resolve the constant from main rather than the current module nesting which is `Api::V1`.

You also need to ensure that `ApplicationController` inherits from `ActionController::API`.

See:

- [Everything you ever wanted to know about constant lookup in Ruby](https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup.html)

Comment: PS. You should also define the module as `API` in allcaps as this follows  the Ruby convention for acronyms. You need to use [ActiveSupport::Inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html) in an initializer.